# C# / SQL Error: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 26,Token in error = user ]

Tags: c#, sql, razor

I can't my mind around this error. The server error point out towards this line:

```
<select name="selectUserName">
        @foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString)) {
          <option>@row.username</option>
        }
      </select>
```

where `selectQueryString` is defined as:

```
var selectQueryString = "SELECT ID, username FROM user";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User is a [reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in SQL Server.  Try:

```
FROM [User]
```

Answer (score 1):

`USER` is a *[`reserved keyword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)* in SQL Server.

You should use it with squared brackets `[]`

Like;

```
var selectQueryString = "SELECT ID, username FROM [USER]";
```